# Need help with column validation on a single line of text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, validation, column-validation

I am looking to validate that my field always starts with the following text before allowing it to be saved "inc", "sctask", "prb", "chg", or "ritm".

I have messed around with the LEFT and MID checks, but cant seem to combine multiple characters:

```
=AND(LEFT([Ticket Number],1)="i",(MID([Ticket Number],2,1)="n"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula for column validation:

```
=OR(LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="inc",LEFT([Ticket Number],6)="sctask",LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="prb",LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="chg",LEFT([Ticket Number],4)="ritm")
```

**Documentation**: [LEFT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-function-913824b4-fc42-4c8c-9229-0eaa57dcdf49)

Comment: amazing! I am wondering if i could add a condition for when the field is blank? Currently for some specific list items i need to allow it to be blank as well.  how would i do that?  I am doing list validation stuff as well and it allows a blank value for certain options and requires info for others.

Comment: I was actually able to use what you provided me to update the formula to allow blanks.  =OR(LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="inc",LEFT([Ticket Number],6)="sctask",LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="prb",LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="chg",LEFT([Ticket Number],4)="ritm",LEFT([Ticket Number],3)="req",([Ticket Number]=""))  Thanks for you help

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.